# Using NPM in the new Windows Bash

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bash, windows-10

I've been playing around with the new [bash terminal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl/about) in Windows 10 to see if I can switch over to a Windows dev environment.

Since the environment is fairly new and still in beta, it's been tricky to google solutions to the many difficulties I've come across (gave up on installing zsh day one for example).

This one has me scratching my head, though. I pulled down one of our larger node/javascript repos and tried a simple `npm install`, which led to a shasum check fail. Just to do a sanity check, I successfully `npm install`ed on the same machine, in the same repo, from native Powershell. Below is the full error log. Any ideas what would cause this?

```
A-Big-Repo$ npm install
npm ERR! Linux 3.4.0+
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1

npm ERR! shasum check failed for /tmp/npm-12392-1219ca0a/registry.npmjs.org/html-webpack-plugin/-/html-webpack-plugin-2.17.0.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: 40d4e0010191d8f4d18b7843d713bc5ea3fcbae8
npm ERR! Actual:   ff675ca416925b6cf190a2d8261dcc66cc627a84
npm ERR! From:     https://registry.npmjs.org/html-webpack-plugin/-/html-webpack-plugin-2.17.0.tgz
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /mnt/c/Users/tehee/npm-debug.log
komali2@C: /mnt/c/Users/tehee$ npm install
npm ERR! Linux 3.4.0+
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1

npm ERR! shasum check failed for /tmp/npm-12401-44f0bedc/registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-4.13.4.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: 3c0b76f3c77590c8345739061ec0bd3ba067ec24
npm ERR! Actual:   b13afa9beceda4401bad4868333c7b77f61aa1b4
npm ERR! From:     https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-4.13.4.tgz
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /myfiles/no/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like network connections are getting dropped randomly.  Every time I run an npm install it gets cut off in a different file in a random location.

Update: Sounds like network is just buggy for now.
https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/194

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue open here for shasum fails on larger packages, small packages seem to be ok https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/348